# Find a second linearly independent solution $y_2(t)$ (simplify and obtain an integral representation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have this exercise but I´m not really sure if what I´m doing is ok, as we haven´t seen it in class yet. Any hint would be appreciated, thanks!!

In quantum mechanics, the study of the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom leads to a consideration of Laguerre´s equation:
$$ ty''+(1-t)y'+λy=0 $$ where λ is a parameter, consider λ=2.
Find a second linearly independent solution $y_2(t)$

This is what I have (it´s not much, but I don´t know if I´m going on the correct path).

$$y=vy_1$$
$$\Rightarrow y=v(t^2-4t+2)$$
$$\Rightarrow y=vt^2-4vt+2v$$

Sorry, I forgot to write the first solution. It´s $$y_1(t)=t^2-4t+2$$

Comment: You wrote *Find a second linearly independent solution $y_2(t)$*... What is the first one?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, Just edited it

Comment: It´s a function of t, sorry. Another typo

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks!